# Не работает авторизация по userDetailsService. Invalid username and password

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final UserService userService;

public WebSecurityConfig(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/registration")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userService)
            .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
}
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
private final UserRepo userRepo;

public UserService(UserRepo userRepo) {
    this.userRepo = userRepo;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return userRepo.findByUsername(username);
}
}
```

**UserRepo.java**

```
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isActive();
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

}
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<div th:insert="parts/_header :: header"></div>
<div th:insert="parts/_menu :: menu"></div>

<body>

<div style="margin-left:20px" class="ui mini breadcrumb">
    <a class="section" href="#">Главная</a>
    <i class="right angle icon divider"></i>
    <div class="active section">Авторизация или регистрация</div>
</div>

<div class="ui raised very padded text container segment">
    <h2>Авторизация</h2>
    <div th:if="${param.error}">
        Invalid username and password.
    </div>
    <div th:if="${param.logout}">
        You have been logged out.
    </div>
    <form class="ui form" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Имя пользователя</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Имя пользователя"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Пароль</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль"/>
        </div>
        <button class="ui button" type="submit" style="margin-top: 20px">Войти</button>

        <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form>

    <div class="ui divider"></div>
    <div>
        Нет аккаунта? <a href="/registration"> Зарегистрируйтесь</a>
    </div>


</div>

<div th:insert="parts/_footer :: footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У вас таблица называется `usr`? И посмотрите, что приходит в контроллере

Comment: Да, таблица называется usr. До этого использовал 'auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, active from usr where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username, ur.roles from usr u inner join user_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id where u.username=?");' все работало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю проблема связана с тем, что вы не внедрили зависимости и определить AuthenticationProvider(в нашем случае DaoAuthenticationProvider), настроить или отключить csrf, указать название полей username, password в loginPage которые будем вытаскивать и создавать UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken:

**UserService.java**:

```
    @Component(value = "customUserDetailsService")
    public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepo userRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepo userRepo) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    }
    }
```

- внедрить зависимость UserRepo с помощью конструктора через аннотацию
  @Autowired
- поменять аннотацию @Service на @Component,т.к. @Service в    основном
  используют для классов описывающих бизнес логику,а    @Component
  более обобщенная аннотация
- указать название бина @Component(value = "customUserDetailsService"),
  т.к. помимо вашей есть и другие реализации в Spring(для избежания
  конфликтов)

**WebSecurityConfig.java**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final UserService userService;

@Autowired
public WebSecurityConfig(@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService") UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}
   
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/registration")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
}


@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthProvider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    daoAuthProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
    return daoAuthProvider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthProvider());
}
}
```

- внедряем зависимость UserService userService благодаря аннотации
  @Autowired над конструктором WebSecurityConfig.
- с помощью @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService") указываем бин с
  определенным названием("customUserDetailsService"), который имеет
  соответствующую реализацию.
- определяем AuthenticationProvider с помощью которого будет
  осуществлять аутентификация, в данной ситуации
  DaoAuthenticationProvider.Рассмотрим подробнее: когда ваш запрос
  проходит по FilterChain и дойдет до
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, то так как в вашем запросе
  будут содержаться username и password, он их вытащит и на их основе
  создаст UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password,)
  после данный объект аутентификации передастся AuthenticationManager,
  который будет искать подходящий AuthenticationProvider поддерживающий
  аутентификацию объекта UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken и
  наткнется как раз на наш DaoAuhenticationProvider, который в свою
  очередь использует UserDetailsService - лезет в бд и ищет нашего
  юзера, на основе данных юзера создаст UserDetails() содержащий
  username, password,GrantedAuthority. В итоге UserDetailsService
  возвращает UserDetails и сравнивает данные UserDetails с данными
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, если они совпадают то все ок,
  иначе ошибка.

**login.html**

Предлагаю отключить csrf если вы не знаете как его настраивть:

- удалить или закоментить строчку `<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />`
- отключить csrf: `http.csrf().disable()`

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Но не помогло(

Comment: извиняюсь, забыл добавить DaoAuthenticatioProvider, исправил ответ

Comment: Не работает( Что же я делаю не так, вроде больше никакие классы не используются в аутентификации

Comment: дополнил ответ, касательно csrf, теперь думаю заработает

Comment: достал уже наверное))) не работает :(. Может на гите посмотрите? (https://github.com/ShiroHayabusa/temp)

Comment: я понял в чем дело, вы этом классе https://github.com/ShiroHayabusa/temp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/loripin/auto/model/User.java, в методе getPassword() возвращает null, сделайте return password

Comment: спасибо огромное! получилось!